# Translation of a hash keys with i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, hash, internationalization

I have a hash of keys/values where my keys are Dates at Month/Year format,

```
{"Apr 2016"=>6.0, "May 2016"=>6.0, "Jun 2016"=>6.0, "Jul 2016"=>6.0, "Aug 2016"=>7.5, "Sep 2016"=>7.5, "Oct 2016"=>7.5, "Nov 2016"=>7.5, "Dec 2016"=>7.5, "Jan 2017"=>8.666666666666666, "Feb 2017"=>8.666666666666666, "Mar 2017"=>8.666666666666666, "Apr 2017"=>6.4, "May 2017"=>6.833333333333333, "Jun 2017"=>6.0, "Jul 2017"=>6.375}
```

I display it in a chart with chartkick/chartjs

I want translate the keys in french months format,
I try to translate it when i create my hash but nothing work the dates display still in english

Comment: Can you give an example of "french months format"? You mean just having french words for months?

Comment: Can you provide the hash after translating?

Comment: Yes just have french words, i would like something like Avr 2016, Mai 2016, Jui 2016....

Comment: The problem is you don't know how to translate those dates into french or chartjs not displaying the dates in french?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure `gem "i18n"` in Gemfile.

1. Verify the `I18n.locale` in `rails console`. It should be `:fr`.
2. Verify if the file `config/locales/fr.yml` exist ?
3. Verify if the snippet below exist in the file fr.yml :

---

```
date:
  formats:
    default: "%d/%m/%Y"
    default_with_day_name: "%a %d/%m/%Y"
    short: "%e %b"
    long: "%e %B %Y"
    long_with_abbr_month: "%e %b %Y"
    long_with_day_name: "%a %e %B %Y"
    long_with_full_day_name: "%A %e %B %Y"
    long_ordinal: "%e %B %Y"
    month_name: "%B"
    only_day: "%e"
    day_name: "%a"
    only_day_and_month: "%d/%m"
    only_month_and_year: "%b %Y"

  day_names: [dimanche, lundi, mardi, mercredi, jeudi, vendredi, samedi]
  abbr_day_names: [dim, lun, mar, mer, jeu, ven, sam]
  month_names: [~, janvier, février, mars, avril, mai, juin, juillet, août, septembre, octobre, novembre, décembre]
  abbr_month_names: [~, jan., fév., mar., avr., mai, juin, juil., août, sept., oct., nov., déc.]
  order:
    - :day
    - :month
    - :year
```

If everything is ok, you can do this:

```
I18n.l('2017-07-30'.to_date, :format => :only_month_and_year) # => "juil. 2017"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `rails-i18n`, set the locale and use `#localize` method along with `format` directive.

What you'll need to do after adding `gem rails-i18n` to the Gemfile and `bundle` :

```
[1] pry(main)> I18n.locale = :fr
=> :fr
[2] pry(main)> I18n.l(Date.parse("Apr 2016"), format: '%B %Y')
=> "avril 2016"
[3] pry(main)> I18n.l(Date.parse("Apr 2016"), format: '%b %Y')
=> "avr. 2016"
[4] pry(main)> I18n.l(Date.parse("1st of Apr 2016"), format: '%A %b %Y')
=> "vendredi avr. 2016"
```

Even easier if you don't parse the string and have them directly as dates.

For more information on how to use format you can check [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) docs.